# Creating a Method object with method while ignoring all class's public_methods

Tags: ruby, class, public-method

So I'm making a gem and I've already had great input on it. Unfortunately there's a pretty important bug in it. This gem creates events that you can attach callbacks to, unfortunately, if you have a callback or an event with the same name as one of the class's public_methods, it bugs out. Here's a working example of the gem's bug with some test code underneath it:

```
# Portion of gem that causes bug
class DemoClass
  def initialize method_symbol
    @method = to_method(method_symbol)
  end

  def call(*args)
    @method.call(*args)
  end

  def some_private_method
    puts 'the private method was called (still bugged)'
  end

  private

  def to_method(method_symbol)
    # this right here references public methods when I don't want it to
    method(method_symbol)
  end
end

# Outside the gem
def some_method
  puts 'this is an original method being called'
end

def some_private_method
  puts 'the private method was NOT called. Bug fixed!'
end

non_bugged_instance = DemoClass.new(:some_method)
bugged_instance = DemoClass.new(:some_private_method)

non_bugged_instance.call
bugged_instance.call
```

Is there any way to have the private method `to_method` create method objects with the symbol `:add` that doesn't refer to the public method `add`, but instead the method that would be outside of that class?

Comment: It seems like the simplest solution here would be to have your to_method and trigger methods quietly rename the callbacks by adding a prefix.

Comment: Sorry about not putting the entire gem in there, but I intend on people being able to edit the callbacks dynamically. So changing the user input isn't much of an option.

Comment: Why are you giving the full code? Give us only the code part which made you confused...It will help us to help you out.

Comment: Updated so it only has minimum amount of code to reproduce the problem. The problem only arises when you change the name of the method `addme` to `add` and the symbol `:addme` to `:add`. It's not really confusing me, I know the problem. I just don't know of any possible solution.

Comment: To me it seems by giving a block as the parameter to would be a better choice. But it depends on what you want these code blocks to be like.

Comment: The purpose of the gem is the same as backbone.js. It gives the ability to dynamicaly "trigger" a callback whenever you call a method. The callbacks could be methods already defined and referenced by symbols or strings, a method or a proc object, or another instance of the Trigger class that isn't in the code because I got fussed at for "giving the full code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code demonstare an example of passing a method deficed in the 'main' into a class via initializer.

```
class DemoClass
  def initialize method
    @method = method
  end

  def touch *args
    puts 'touch'
    @method.call *args
  end   
end

# Outside the gem
def some_method
  puts 'Unbugged method'
end

def some_private_method
  puts 'Bugged method'
end

non_bugged_instance = DemoClass.new( self.method :some_method )
bugged_instance = DemoClass.new( self.method :some_private_method )

puts "Non bugged touch"
non_bugged_instance.touch

puts "Bugged touch"
bugged_instance.touch
```

And output:

```
Non bugged touch
touch
Unbugged method
Bugged touch
touch
Bugged method
```

If you strongly wish to use only method names replace the class initializer with the following:

```
def initialize method_name
  @method = Kernel.method method_name
end
```

And class creation call to as:

```
non_bugged_instance = DemoClass.new :some_method
bugged_instance = DemoClass.new :some_private_method
```

But I earnestly advise to use the first option.

Comment: The problem with that is that it's extra typing. You're creating a method object and then passing that method through the arguments. I want it to be much more simple than that by a user just having to type `DemoClass.new(:some_method)`.

Comment: Please see the additionals.

Comment: Alright, it works and is much better than `self.class.superclass.method` I just hope it works in the correct scope.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so apparently, in order to reference the methods outside of the `DemoClass`, I needed to use the `superclass` method. Apparently, you also need to reference `self.class` or else it will try to call a public method named `superclass`. All together it will look like this:

```
# Portion of gem that causes bug
class DemoClass
  def initialize method_symbol
    @method = to_method(method_symbol)
  end

  def call(*args)
    @method.call(*args)
  end

  def some_private_method
    puts 'the private method was called (still bugged)'
  end

  private

  def to_method(method_symbol)
    # this right here references superclass methods like it's supposed to
    self.class.superclass.method(method_symbol)
  end
end

# Outside the gem
def some_method
  puts 'this is an original method being called'
end

def some_private_method
  puts 'the private method was NOT called. Bug fixed!'
end

non_bugged_instance = DemoClass.new(:some_method)
bugged_instance = DemoClass.new(:some_private_method)

non_bugged_instance.call
bugged_instance.call
```